# How to theme the node edit form to group fields into collapsible containers?

Tags: 7, theming, forms

I'd like to tidy up an unwieldy node edit form using collapsible [`fieldset` elements](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#fieldset).

I can do this by implementing a form_alter hook but will this affect Drupal/other modules' ability to process/validate the fields? Obviously it will change the `#parents` of several elements, and I'm unclear whether this change will also affect `$form_state['values']`.

Is it safe to do this, or is there another way to achieve the same?

### Example code

```
$form['group1'] = [
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => 'My Grouped Fields',
  '#collapsible' => TRUE,
  '#collapsed' => TRUE,
  'children' => [
    'body' => $form['body'],
    'field_smallprint' => $form['field_smallprint']
    ],
  ];
unset($form['body'], $form['field_smallprint']);
```

It seems to me that this is probably safe unless `#tree` is `TRUE`, but I don't want to implement something that might lose data, hence the question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to first try the [Field Group module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) that provides the option to do that kind of grouping and many more options.